# Compute eigenvalues of a regular graph.

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I have a $(q^2+q)(q+1)$-regular graph. Is there some general method to compute the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of a $k$-regular graph explicitly? Or could we estimate its eigenvalues? Thank you very much.

Edit: I would like to know the bound of $$max_i(|\lambda_i|),$$
where $\lambda_i$ runs over all eigenvalues except the ones with $|\lambda|=k$.

Comment: The largest eigenvalue is $k$.

Comment: Sometimes if your graph has enough nice structure you can write down other eigenvalues. It might be worth describing your graph if possible.

Comment: @Casteels, thank you very much. The graph has $(q^4-1)(q^4-q)/((q^2-1)(q^2-q))$ vertices.

Comment: Ok so I'm guessing the vertices correspond to the $2$-dimensional subspaces of a $4$-dimensional vector space over $GF(q)$? And what is the rule for adjacency? It could be that your graph is known already, that's why I ask.

Comment: @Casteels, thank you very much. Yes, the vertices are the 2-dim subspaces of $F_q^4$. Two 2-dim subspaces $w_1, w_2$ are adjacent if and only if $w_1\cap w_2 \neq \{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph is indeed nice. In fact it's a Grassmann graph, also known as a Grassmann (association) scheme or $q$-Johnson graph. It's especially nice in your case because it's [strongly-regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph) and so the eigenvalues can be written down explicitly. Fortunately it's already done [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/Grassmann.html). In particular, the eigenvalues of your graph are $(q^2+q)(q+1)$, $q^2-1$ and $-q-1$.

Comment: thank you very much. Do you know where could we find a reference about the computation of these eigenvalues?

Comment: For your purposes, perhaps Van Lint and Wilson "A Course in Combinatorics" might be best, but Godsil and Royle "Algebraic Graph Theory" is also excellent.

Comment: thank you very much. Do you know some references about [this graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586639/reference-request-the-graph-b-i-j)?